# Looking for example of function that satisfies a lipschitz-like condition

Tags: probability, analysis, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Im reading a paper. In this text introduce a condition very similar to the definition of a fuction be lipschitz.

[image]

$A$ is a compact space, $m\in\mathbb{P}(S)$ ($\mathbb{P}(S)$ space of probabilities of $s$ components, example $m\in\mathbb{P}(3), m=(1/4,1/4,2/4)$), $L_r>0$ a constant.

$||m-m'||_{\infty}=\max{\{|m_1-m_1'|,...,|m_s-m_s'|\}}$

Looking for fuctions than maybe satisfies this condition.

I already try using combinations of functions with the form

$r(m,a)=g(a)(m_1+...+m_s)$

and $g(a)$ be exponential, and log, but with no success.

Comment: The above implies $r(m,a) = r(m,a')$ for all $m$, $a,a' \in A$.

Comment: I have not notice this property. I will explore functions that satisfies it. Thank you.